# On a conceptual question on inequalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

Prologue: $a > b\implies a^2>b^2$ will hold only when $|a| > | b|$.

So I was messing with this inequality for quite some time

$$\sqrt{8+2x-x^2}>6-3x$$

- First things first I found out that the common domain of this inequality is actually $[-2,4]$.
- when $6-3x <0$ or $x>2$ the inequality holds for $(2,\infty)$

When $6-3x \leq0$, the author squared the inequality or in other words " $a^2>b^2$ followed" which in turn implied that

$$\left|\sqrt{ 8+2x-x^2}\right| > |6-3x|$$ holds in order for "$>$" to remain intact.

How do I be sure about this?

Comment: I think you are stuck at why when $6-3x \geq 0$ (rather than $<$ which you wrote), the author could square the inequality on both sides. This is because if both $a$ and $b$ are $\geq 0$, then $$a^2>b^2\implies a>b$$, hence if you know $6-3x\geq 0$, you can square both sides and solve $$8+2x-x^2\geq (6-3x)^2$$ to get your answer, provided the left hand side is in the correct domain

Comment: $a>b\implies a^2 > b^2$ is also true when $a\le b$, just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\sqrt{8+2x-x^2}>6-3x\tag{*}$$
>
> - First things first I found out that the common domain of this inequality is actually $[-2,4]$.
> - when $6-3x <0$ or $x>2$ the inequality holds for $(2,\infty)$

Note that the second bullet point is wrong. As you have observed, 
$$
8+2x-x^2\geq 0
$$
if and only if $x\in[-2,4]$. This means that the solution set to ($*$) must be a subset of $S:=[-2,4]$ and one should not bother with any point outside this set. Now there are obviously two cases to consider:

- $x\in[-2,4]$ *and* $6-3x<0$; namely, $x\in(2,4]$.
- $x\in[-2,4]$ *and* $6-3x\geq 0$; namely, $x\in[-2,2]$.

For the first case, one can see that *any* $x\in(2,4]$ is a solution to ($*$).

For the second case, note that you are comparing two *nonnegative* real numbers and for $a,b\geq 0$,

> $a>b$ **if and only if** $a^2>b^2$.

Thus when $x\in[-2,2]$, ($*$) is equivalent to
$$
8+2x-x^2>(6-3x)^2.
$$

Comment: Listen when x >2 , let x=3, * gives root 5 > -3 which is true.

Comment: So, what is your point?

Comment: Imagine graphically. The term with squareroot lies entirely above x axis.Also as 6-3x is a straight line with negetive slope, with x axis intercept at x=2. Beyond that it gives negetive output for entire set(2,infinity).so this is also a "part" of solution.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. *Any* point outside the interval $[-2,4]$ can **not** be a solution because $8+2x-x^2<0$, which makes the expression $\sqrt{8+2x-x^2}$ nonsense.

Comment: I get it now thanx

Comment: [You are welcome](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).